# Load Array values values from Controller: MVC WInforms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, model-view-controller

I'm working on the MVC Pattern Winforms example project from [this website](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp)

Program.cs

```
static void Main()
        {

            UserView view = new UserView();
            view.Visible = false;

            UserController controller =  new UserController(view, listLoad());
            controller.LoadView();
            view.ShowDialog();
        }

 private static IList listLoad()
        {
            var users = new ArrayList();
            users.Add(new User("Vladimir", "Putin", "122", "Government of Russia", User.SexOfPerson.Male));

            return users;
        }
```

[image]

```
 public  void SaveXML()
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_users.GetType());

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\test\Users.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(fileStream, _users);
            }
        }
```

What is the problem with the above code?

*Question 1*: How can i add the user values from the controller instead of loading from the program.cs file `IList users = new ArrayList();` ?

*Question 2*: I want to save all the rows of the list into a XML file, what is the best of way do it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say **add the user values from the controller**, what exactly do you mean? Could you not have a method called "AddUsers" on the controller to do that? I appreciate that you would have to stop IList _users from being readonly to do so, however...

As for writing to an XML file, I'd say your best best is XML Serialisation. To do this, you'd probably want to do something like the following in the controller:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_users.GetType());            

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("Users.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    serializer.Serialize(fileStream, _users);
}
```

Comment: :I have changed a bit in the program.cs file. I have a method to load the new user values. I want to have a method in the controller and call the method in the program.cs file. How can i do this??

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused, do you want a method in the controller that you want to call the private listLoad() method from the Program.cs?

Comment: No, How can I load all the values in the controller in some method and call that method in the program.cs file? I got a problem in saving the XML file?.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's complaining about that Xml serialisation... I got that too when I tried to do the same thing in my code. A way around that would be to use List<User> _users = new List<User>(); rather than IList _users = new ArrayList();. However, a final step to get the serialisation to work is to add a parameterless constructor to the User class... is that something you are able to do?

With regard to you wanting to add users from the Main area of the program... I'm not sure I understand why you'd want to do that... it doesn't make much sense when I look at the code from CodeProject.

Comment: As per your suggestion, i have created a empty constructor in the model and changed the Array into List...Finally everything is working fine.